# Hi! I am new with bootstrap and I would like to do the following layout responsive and to be situated on the middle of the page

Tags: angular, layout, bootstrap-4, grid

This is the layout that i am going for

[image]

This is my current code

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <h2 class="title mt-3 mb-4">Title</h2> 
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col"> 
        firts 
      </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col"> 
        second 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code

Comment: <div class="container">
    <h2 class="title mt-3 mb-4">Title</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                firts
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                second
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: I've added this to your question - it's much better there where other people can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your project in ***.container*** class of bootstrap and add some css.

Check my answer in https://codepen.io/Arnab_Datta/pen/xxwgryd

```css
.middlePage{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}

.proj{
    width: 100%;
}

.middlediv{
  width: 100% ;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px 0px;
}
.custBtn{
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #dc3545 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="middlePage">
            <div class="proj">
                <h1>TITLE</h1>

                <div class="middlediv"></div>
                <div class="middlediv"></div>

                <div class="btn btn-outline-danger custBtn">button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```